# I would like NOT to add the same value to local Storage

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new in code. Please help. I am saving inputs to local storage. I input several todo list like sleep, shopping, study and so on. If I add shopping or sleep again, It will add it again to `localStorage` although sleep or shopping are already exist. How can I write a alert code NOT to add the exist todo to local storage.

[image]

```
const newtodo = document.querySelector("#todo")
const form = document.querySelector("#todo-form");

form.addEventListener("submit", addtodoToLocalStorage);


function addtodoToLocalStorage(e) {

  const value = newtodo.value;
  let todos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("input") === null) {

    todos = [];
  }
  else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("input"))
  }

  todos.push(value);
  localStorage.setItem("input", JSON.stringify(todos))
  newtodo.value = "";


  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Check on every input, that the value entered is there already in local storage or not. Then proceed accordingly.

Comment: See [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Answer (score 0):

Like Will noted, this can be easily accomplished with [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

In this case it would look something like:

```
if (todos.includes(value)) {
  alert('Value already present in todos');
} else {
  todos.push(value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric HB for that.

Comment: If that answer works for you, feel free to accept it! :)